# How to allow Android users to upgrade to a newer version of the APK/targetSDK

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, apk

My Ionic2 Android app (ver 1.3.0) is live in Google Play and the APK has an SDK version of 23.
It did not have a targetSDK version set in config.xml (only a minSDK of 16).

I then removed my local Android platform and readded it with the latest Ionic CLI tools (3). I noticed that it was now set to SDK of 25. I used Ionic Cloud to package my app and generate a new release APK (1.4.0).

When I uploaded it to Google Play, I received a message "Non-upgradable APK". I could not find any information on it and published my app, which was a mistake.

Now NEW users can install the new version (SDK 25) but all existing users of the app cannot. They can see the new version in Google play but it just says "Open", not "Update".

I tried to do a new build with a specific version of 23 - 1.4.1 which worked. 
`<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>`

I could not see a way to roll back to 1.3.0 and publish 1.4.1, so I published 1.4.1 and deactivated 1.4.0.

However the original users of 1.3.0 STILL cannot upgrade to 1.4.1 version and it looks like they will be stuck on that version. The 1.4.0 users can upgrade to 1.4.1.

My question is:  How can I make my new build compatible with the old users (is it something to do with the TargetSDK version or not?)

And if so, how do I migrate everyone onto 25 (the latest)?

**EDIT:**  This might be completely wrong, I think the answer to this question will solve this issue:  **[What causes this Android APK Upload error: "Non-upgradable APK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061660/what-causes-this-android-apk-upload-error-non-upgradable-apk)